# Spring + Hibernate: Create database from DDL rather than using annotated model classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Objective**

I am trying to setup a test environment for a Spring and Hibernate based web application, using an in memory database which is currently automatically created based on provided annotated model classes.

**Problem**

Rather than using the model classes to create the database, Hibernate should use a DDL file to create the database.

**Question**

Is this possible and if the answer is 'Yes', how could I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can generate a database from SQL file (rather than DDL).

Once you have created your dataSource bean (I'm assuming in the XML file) just add the following

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/location/of/your/sql/script" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

You can include as many `jdbc:script`'s as you like, and can even specify if they are to be used in the creation or destruction of your database.

Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch12s09.html) for more informaton.